# Paragraph numbering?

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to coding, and am currently teaching myself html/css and i found that my paragraphs weren't centering in the middle of the page. I'd had my headline and sub headline labelled as h1 and h2, so i thought naturally the paragraphs would be the same (even though they had exactly the same declarations), yet when i changed both the elements to just p and brought them both under the same selector it worked. I was wondering if p1/p2 using would cause a lot of problems in the future? (this was before i was learning about ID's and classes, would that be the correct way to differentiate between paragraphs instead?)
please be kind, I've been learning less than a couple weeks:)

Comment: Show us your html+css and explain your problem more clearly please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p1` and `p2` are not valid HTML elements in themselves.

Granted, with HTML5, you can define your own elements where necessary, however this is usually reserved for instances where it makes your markup more semantic, and usually with a front-end framework or such.

With paragraphs, if you must differentiate between them, then I would suggest using classes.

```
<h1>Heading One</h1>
<h2>Heading Two</h2>
<p class="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean volutpat efficitur magna eget tincidunt.</p>
<p class="p2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean volutpat efficitur magna eget tincidunt.</p>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for clearing that up, I kind of worked it out, but needed some help. The resource I'm learning from didn't mention anything about not numbering, so i treated it the same as the h element. I also didn't realise you could add an ID to p element itself, the site i'm learning from only uses a <div id="ghfuf"> to nest elements? This really helped though, thank you :)

Comment: No worries. Heading tags, `h1` through `h6` are the only numbered elements in HTML. All other elements you differentiate using CSS selectors.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Paragraphs are always `<p>`. Only the header elements have this kind of numbering.

Answer (score 0):

My personal reccomendation would be to use ***ID's*** rather than ***Classes***. This is due to the nature of what seem to you want in your question.

***ID's*** are unique - meaning that there can only be one of them per page.

***Classes*** aren't unique - meaning that they can be assigned to multiple objects per page.

```
<p id="one">This is paragraph one.</p>
<p id="two">This is paragraph two.</p>
```

Comment: @RyanJudd - here's a good resource that explains IDs and classes further. https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Comment: That's a great resource to help determine how they may want to go about the design of their page!